# How do I split a random value into an array of characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, split

I'm trying generate random lat and lng positions and I want to use this false data with javascript and put it in a `p` with different `span`

```
//  latitude

var latMin = parseInt(-90);
var latMax = parseInt(90);
var latAnswer = document.getElementById("latitude");
var lat = Math.floor(Math.random() * (latMax - latMin + 1) + latMin);
var latSplit = lat.split('');

console.log(latSplit);
console.log('lat:'+lat);

$( latSplit ).insertAfter( '#latAfter' );

//  longitude

var lngMin = parseInt(-180);
var lngMax = parseInt(180);
var lngAnswer = document.getElementById("longitude");
var lng = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lngMax - lngMin + 1) + lngMin);
var lngSplit = lng.split('');

console.log(lngSplit);
console.log('lng:'+lng);

$( lngSplit ).insertAfter( '#lngAfter' );
```

And then, in my result, I wanna have something like that `<span>3</span><span>8</span><span>.</span><span class="end">7</span>` then I want to split in different `div` with a class in the last

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand the question correctly. But have you tried mapping the array to add the tags around it? `var latSpans = latSplit.map(function( lat, index ) { return '<span>' + lat + '</span>'; } );` The index can then tell you when you reached the last value to add the class.

Comment: The first problem is that the `var latSplit = lat.split('');` doesn't run

Comment: Add `.toString()` to it. lat is a number and hence, does not have the `.split()` method by default. `var latSplit = lat.toString().split('');` Keep in mind that your random function will also return negative numbers. So latSplit will have `-` as the first element sometimes.

Comment: Thank you ! It runs, and is it possible to put a `class` on the last span ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution. I would not advice to create entire pages with this method, that's why we have templates. But for very basic HTML, strings suffice.

```
// lat is a number, so cast it to a string to be able to use the split method.
var latSplit = lat.toString().split('');
// Simple loop surrounding the values with spans.
var latLength = lat.length;
var latSpans = lat.map( function( value, index ) {
    if ( index + 1 === latLength ) return '<span class="end">' + value + '</span>';
    else return '<span>' + value + '</span>';
} );
var latHTML = '<p>' + latSpans.join('') + '</p>';
```

Comment: There was an error on `lat.length` and `lat.map` it was latSplit, but everything run ! Thank you